# Getting 'org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!' randomly

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a java application running on weblogic server. I am using Hibernate for all CRUD operations. Problem is I am getting the following exception on production randomly. As a result it brings the application to a halt and then there is no other way but to redeploy the application. I cannot replicate this issue on test. I am assuming the issue is on production because of more user activity compared to test. The error is

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:130)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.setFlushMode(SessionImpl.java:1356)
```

My service class has the following method as an example:

```
public DOCustomer query(){
    DOCustomer data = new DOCustomer ();
    Transaction tx=null;
    Session s =null;
    try{
        GenericDAO dao = HibernateDAOFactory.getInstance().getDAO(GenericClassDAO.class, DOCustomer.class);
        s = SessionService.createNewSession(dao);
        tx = SessionService.startNewTransaction(s);
        Criteria cr = s.createCriteria(DOCustomer.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("recordID", recordID));
        
        data = (DOCustomer) cr.uniqueResult();
        SessionService.commitTransaction(s);
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        s.close();
    }
    return data;
}
```

SessionService.java

```
public class SessionService {

 public static org.hibernate.Session createNewSession(GenericDAO dao) {
    Session s = dao.getSession();
    s.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
    ManagedSessionContext.bind(s);
    return s;
 }

 public static Transaction startNewTransaction(Session session) {
    return session.beginTransaction();
 }

 public static void commitTransaction(Session session) {
    ManagedSessionContext.unbind(HibernateUtil.getSessionAnnotationFactory());
    try {
        session.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error flushing: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error commiting transaction: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

GenericClassDAO.java

```
public class GenericClassDAO extends GenericDAOImpl { }
```

GenericDAOImpl.java

```
public abstract class GenericDAOImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDAO {

private Session session;
private Class clazz;


@Override
public void setSession(Session s) {
    this.session = s;
}

@Override
public Session getSession() {

    if (this.session == null) {

        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Session must be an instance of an object.");
    }
    return this.session;
}

@Override
public T query(Class clazz, Serializable id) {

    try {
        return (T) getSession().get(clazz, id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public Serializable save(Object o) {
    System.out.println("from GenericDAOImpl: save");
    try {
        return (ID) getSession().save(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void saveOrUpdate(Object o) {
    System.out.println("from GenericDAOImpl: saveOrUpdate");
    try {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void setDOClass(Class clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

@Override
public Class getDOClass() {
    if (this.clazz == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Domain Class must be defined.");
    }
    return this.clazz;
}
}
```

HibernateDAOFactory.java

```
public class HibernateDAOFactory {
private static final HibernateDAOFactory _instance = new HibernateDAOFactory();

protected HibernateDAOFactory() {
}

public static HibernateDAOFactory getInstance() {
    return _instance;
}

public GenericDAO getDAO(Class daoClass, Class doClass) {
    return instantiateDAO(daoClass, doClass);
}

private GenericDAO instantiateDAO(Class daoClass, Class doClass) {
    GenericDAO dao;
    try {
        dao = (GenericDAO) daoClass.newInstance();

        dao.setDOClass(doClass);

        setSession(dao);

        logger.debug(dao.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Unable to instantiate DAO -" + daoClass, e);
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Unable to instantiate DAO -" + daoClass, e);
    }
    return dao;
}

protected void setSession(GenericDAO dao) {
    try {
        dao.setSession((HibernateUtil.getSessionAnnotationFactory().getCurrentSession()));          
    } catch (Exception e) {           
        dao.setSession((HibernateUtil.getSessionAnnotationFactory().openSession()));          
    }
  }
}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionAnnotationFactory;

private static SessionFactory buildSessionAnnotationFactory() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("building session annotation factory");
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml");
        System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation Configuration loaded");

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation serviceRegistry created");

        try {
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            System.out.println("SF created");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unable to create session factory", e);
        }
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        System.out.println("sf null");
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}


public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
    return sessionAnnotationFactory.openSession();
}

public static void shutdown() {
    try{
        sessionAnnotationFactory.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Error shutting down sessionAnnotationFactory", e);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionAnnotationFactory() {
    if (sessionAnnotationFactory == null) {
        System.out.println("Session Annotation Factory = null");
        sessionAnnotationFactory = buildSessionAnnotationFactory();
    }
    return sessionAnnotationFactory;
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Session Factory successfully initialized!");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to initialize the Session Factory!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.datasource">weblogic.jdbc.datasource.web</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jndi.class">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</property>
    <property name="transaction.manager_lookup_class">
        org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
        org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">managed</property>

    <property name="cache.provider_class">
        org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
    </property>

    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
    </property>

    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="format_sql">false</property>

    <mapping class="com.example.DOCustomer"/>
    <mapping class="com.example.DOCustomerFiles"/>

 </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
 <Error occurred while querying Customer
 org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
 at  org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed 
 (AbstractSessionImpl.java:130)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.setFlushMode(SessionImpl.java:1356)
 at 
com.example.service.SessionService.createNewSession(SessionService.java:18) 
// This is 's.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);'
at com.example.service.CustomerService.queryAll(CustomerService.java:129)
at com.example.servlet.CustomerServlet.execute(CustomerServlet.java:175)
at com.example.servlet.FrontServlet.internalProcessHttpRequest 
(FrontServlet.java:247)
at com.example.servlet.FrontServlet.doGet(FrontServlet.java:173)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run 
(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run 
(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet 
(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute 
(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute 
(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext 
$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun (WebAppServletContext.java:3679)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext 
$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs 
(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode 
(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode 
(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute 
(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute 
(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute 
(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal 
(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run 
(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl 
$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs 
(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs 
(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext 
(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext 
(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext 
(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
>
```

Also, I see the following at some locations:

```
<Self-tuning thread pool contains 1 running threads, 4 idle threads, and 21 standby threads>
```

Does this mean anything specific?

I read somewhere that using the same DAO instance for multiple requests could cause concurrency issues. I am creating a new instance every time so I am not sure what is the issue here. It is is a big application with multiple data objects (hibernate configuration pasted here doesn't reflect all classes), several service classes and of course many methods. Any help enlightening me about the issue here will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Kindly share the whole stack trace.

Comment: Please also check whether your system is leaking JDBC connection and how was the load on the database when these error happened. To detect a JDBC leak you should use the Weblogic console to monitor the connection pool used by your application.

Comment: I included the stack trace. Also I monitored 'Leaked Connection Count' on weblogic console while I played around with the application. It displayed 0 all the while. Is there something else that I could monitor?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that whenever there is an exception thrown (NullPointer, NonUniqueResultException etc), I start getting 'Session is Closed!'. I am not sure why these exceptions should lead to SessionException but fixing these issues solved the SessionException problem. I don't see these in the logs anymore.